# Child div jumping from one div to another

Tags: html, parent-child

I am working on a site here:

[My Site](http://www.frgraphicsolutions.com/working)

The issue I am having is when you shrink the window or view the site on a mobile device the images jump from the div container they are in, (the div id="client") into the widget div below it.

I do not know how to solve this issue and am having a hard time finding the html for the widgets in all the different .php files I have.

I am working on wordpress from a template that I have edited.

I am not sure if this is just a simple css problem or if code if conflicting each other.

If you need more information please let me know. I wasn't sure if posting any code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, all I needed to do is edit the parent div css and add

```
overflow:hidden
```